# selectpicker - error only with more options in the select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

This script shows a year-month dropdown.

When clicking on it to change its value, this error occurs in the Firefox console, without showing the options in the select:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: A.selectpicker.current.data[(v + A.selectpicker.view.position0)] is undefined
>     i bootstrap-select.js:1256
>     createView bootstrap-select.js:1135
>     setSize bootstrap-select.js:2045
>     clickListener bootstrap-select.js:2341
>     jQuery 8
>     checkDisabled bootstrap-select.js:2293
>     init bootstrap-select.js:932
>     J bootstrap-select.js:832
>     t bootstrap-select.js:3050
>     jQuery 2
>     Q bootstrap-select.js:3033
>     <anonymous> bootstrap-select.js:3100
>     jQuery 2
>     <anonymous> bootstrap-select.js:3098
>     jQuery 8
>     <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6
>     <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6 bootstrap-select.js:1256:18
> ```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class='form-control selectpicker' data-live-search='true' data-size='10' data-width='fit' class="select">
<option value="2018-01">2018-01</option>
<option value="2018-02">2018-02</option>
<option value="2018-03">2018-03</option>
<option value="2018-04">2018-04</option>
<option value="2018-05">2018-05</option>
<option value="2018-06">2018-06</option>
<option value="2018-07">2018-07</option>
<option value="2018-08">2018-08</option>
<option value="2018-09">2018-09</option>
<option value="2018-10">2018-10</option>
<option value="2018-11">2018-11</option>
<option value="2018-12">2018-12</option>
<option value="2019-01">2019-01</option>
<option value="2019-02">2019-02</option>
<option value="2019-03">2019-03</option>
<option value="2019-04">2019-04</option>
<option value="2019-05">2019-05</option>
<option value="2019-06">2019-06</option>
<option value="2019-07">2019-07</option>
<option value="2019-08">2019-08</option>
<option value="2019-09">2019-09</option>
<option value="2019-10">2019-10</option>
<option value="2019-11">2019-11</option>
<option value="2019-12">2019-12</option>
<option value="2020-01">2020-01</option>
<option value="2020-02">2020-02</option>
<option value="2020-03">2020-03</option>
<option value="2020-04">2020-04</option>
<option value="2020-05">2020-05</option>
<option value="2020-06">2020-06</option>
<option value="2020-07">2020-07</option>
<option value="2020-08">2020-08</option>
<option value="2020-09">2020-09</option>
<option value="2020-10">2020-10</option>
<option value="2020-11" selected="selected">2020-11</option>
<option value="2020-12">2020-12</option>
<option value="2021-01">2021-01</option>
<option value="2021-02">2021-02</option>
<option value="2021-03">2021-03</option>
<option value="2021-04">2021-04</option>
<option value="2021-05">2021-05</option>
<option value="2021-06">2021-06</option>
<option value="2021-07">2021-07</option>
<option value="2021-08">2021-08</option>
<option value="2021-09">2021-09</option>
<option value="2021-10">2021-10</option>
<option value="2021-11">2021-11</option>
<option value="2021-12">2021-12</option>
<option value="2022-01">2022-01</option>
<option value="2022-02">2022-02</option>
<option value="2022-03">2022-03</option>
<option value="2022-04">2022-04</option>
<option value="2022-05">2022-05</option>
<option value="2022-06">2022-06</option>
<option value="2022-07">2022-07</option>
<option value="2022-08">2022-08</option>
<option value="2022-09">2022-09</option>
<option value="2022-10">2022-10</option>
<option value="2022-11">2022-11</option>
<option value="2022-12">2022-12</option>
</select>
```

But this one, identical but with fewer options, works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class='form-control selectpicker' data-live-search='true' data-size='10' data-width='fit' class="select">
<option value="2018-01">2018-01</option>
<option value="2018-02">2018-02</option>
<option value="2018-03">2018-03</option>
<option value="2018-04">2018-04</option>
<option value="2018-05">2018-05</option>
<option value="2018-06">2018-06</option>
<option value="2018-07">2018-07</option>
<option value="2018-08">2018-08</option>
<option value="2018-09">2018-09</option>
<option value="2018-10">2018-10</option>
<option value="2018-11">2018-11</option>
<option value="2018-12">2018-12</option>
<option value="2019-01">2019-01</option>
<option value="2019-02">2019-02</option>
<option value="2019-03">2019-03</option>
<option value="2019-04">2019-04</option>
<option value="2019-05">2019-05</option>
<option value="2019-06">2019-06</option>
<option value="2019-07">2019-07</option>
<option value="2019-08">2019-08</option>
<option value="2019-09">2019-09</option>
<option value="2019-10">2019-10</option>
<option value="2019-11">2019-11</option>
<option value="2019-12">2019-12</option>
<option value="2020-01">2020-01</option>
<option value="2020-02">2020-02</option>
<option value="2020-03">2020-03</option>
<option value="2020-04">2020-04</option>
<option value="2020-05">2020-05</option>
<option value="2020-06">2020-06</option>
<option value="2020-07">2020-07</option>
<option value="2020-08">2020-08</option>
<option value="2020-09">2020-09</option>
<option value="2020-10">2020-10</option>
<option value="2020-11" selected="selected">2020-11</option>
<option value="2020-12">2020-12</option>
</select>
```

Why?

How to make it work?

Thannks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug that was fixed in `bootstrap-select v1.13.8`...

See: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2231

Changing your CDN import to version

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.8/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

or higher will fix it.

Alternatively, if that's impossible, enabling `virtualScroll` should also fix it.